# simple-spring-memcached upgrade to 4.1.1 causing WrappedCacheException

Tags: java, spring, caching, memcached

I recently upgraded simple-spring-memcached from version 3.6.1 to 4.1.1. However, after this version upgrade, I am getting WrappedCacheException whenever my code is trying to fetch a value from the cache. I am sharing my code snippet below:

```
@Transactional
@Cacheable(value = CACHE_NAME, key = "#id")
@Override
public TicketModel validate(final String id) {
    TicketEntity ticketEntity = ticketEntityRepository.findOne(id);
    if (ticketEntity == null) {
        System.out.println("Ticket not found")
    }
    return something;
}
```

And my cacheManager bean looks like:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() throws Exception {
    List<SSMCache> cacheList = new ArrayList<>();

    CacheFactory cacheFactory;
    if (ELASTIC_CACHE_FACTORY.equals(cacheBean)) {
        cacheFactory = elastiCacheFactory();
    } else {
        cacheFactory = memCacheFactory();
    }

    Cache cache = cacheFactory.getObject();

    SSMCache aamCache = new SSMCache(cache, cacheTimeout, true);
    cacheList.add(aamCache);

    SSMCacheManager cacheManager = new SSMCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(cacheList);
    cacheManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return cacheManager;
}
```

The exact exception that I am getting looks like this:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-servlet] in context with path [/user-service-web] threw exception [com.google.code.ssm.spring.WrappedCacheException] with root cause
com.google.code.ssm.spring.WrappedCacheException
    at com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache.logOrThrow(SSMCache.java:318)
    at com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache.getValue(SSMCache.java:285)
    at com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache.get(SSMCache.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:469)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:435)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
```

Whenever there is a call to findOne(id) method, I get WrappedCacheException and the code fails. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 4.0.0, exceptions thrown from the underlying cache/client layer (e.g. IOExceptions, etc) were eaten by SsmCache object. After 4.0.0, by default, these are thrown to the caller. You can revert to the prior behavior by setting the "muteExceptions" flag to true on the SsmCache bean.